# Function argument in Scala, writing fold

Tags: scala, functional-programming

just curious about what difference is between the following part of the definition

```
abstract class OperationTree {
  def foldOT[T] (flr : (OT, OT) => T, fsv : (Number => T), fs : (String => T), a : OT) : T =
    a match {
      case SimpleValue(v) => fsv(v)
      case SimpleString(s) => fs(s)
      case SimpleOperation(lot, rot, bop) => flr(foldOT[T](flr,fsv,fs,lot) , foldOT[T](flr,fsv,fs,rot))
    }
 }
```

The code  above is correct (i hope!!). But when i wrote it first, the def part was different

```
  def foldOT[T] (flr : (OT, OT => T), fsv : (Number => T), fs : (String => T), a : OT) : T =
```

and with this definition, i got the error (OT, OT => T does not take parameters) does not take parameters.

I wonder flr : (OT, OT => T) really means,

I take advice about whether the class OT is the right place to put the fold. (Im moving it now to the package object anyway)

Thanks!

Comment: @senia Thanks!
I've also just figured out that is a wrong definition of fold :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(OT, OT => T)` means `Tuple2[OT, Function1[OT, T]]`.

i.e. `(T1, T2)`, where `T1` is `OT` and `T2` is `OT => T`.

In general the type `(T1, T2, T3, ..., TN)` is a *tuple* of arity `N` (i.e. with `N` elements).

Instead if you want to write functions, the corresponding type is:

```
(T1, T2, T3, ..., TN) => R
```

which corresponds to a *function* object of `N` arguments and result `R`

```
FunctionN[-T1, -T2,..., -TN, +R]
```

Comment: @pagoda_5b: Thank you for edits you suggested. It was rejected by other reviewers, so I have applied it manually.